# Nuxt 3 how to define multi lang routing via use user prefered lang?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

How to define multi lang routes via use user prefered lang. I mean for example i have constant routes which are home.vue about.vue and terms.vue so if the user select the fr lang then i want to show the about.vue url like this [www.somesite.com/aproposde-nous](http://www.somesite.com/aproposde-nous)

Nuxt define multi lang routes

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?